# Creating a parent route in Vue Router without a path causes it to match the root route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I have a Vue Router setup with a homepage with a path of '/', then I also separately have a parent template, which is a header and footer. This parent has children. I don't want the parent to have a path, only its children. However, when I have the parent and children listed below the home page and leave the path blank, the parent loads when the base URL is navigated to instead of the home page. Am I going about this wrong?

```
routes: [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: HomeView
},
{
  component: HeaderFooter,
  children: [
    {
      path: '/category',
      component: CategoryView
    }
  ]
},
```

I'll add in the HeaderFooter component just for clarity. It's just a component with the header, footer and a router view so I can apply the header and footer to all pages that I want to have them easily from the router.

```
<script>
import TheHeader from '../components/TheHeader.vue'
import TheFooter from '../components/TheFooter.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        TheHeader,TheFooter
    }
}
</script>
<template>
    <the-header></the-header>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <the-footer></the-footer>
</template>
```

Comment: I think your question is not clear. What do you mean by ```a parent template```? If it is a component for header (footer) or a page? If it is a page, I think it must  have a path. Maybe posting the component or page codes could help that your question becomes clear.

Comment: There is no documentation on what happens when you omit path but you've certainly confused vue-router. vue-router 3 would throw an error when path was omitted, so it may be a bug that vue-router 4 does not. Regardless, you should consider path required. Even logically, of course the parent must have a path, otherwise what does the child path append to?  If you elaborate on what URLs should display what component layouts maybe we can help you figure out the appropriate routing.

Comment: So to state it another way, I don’t want the homepage to have the header and footer but I do want the category page and future other pages to have the header and footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don’t want the homepage to have the header and footer but I do want the category page and future other pages to have the header and footer.

My answer will be a response to this comment since it gets to the heart of what you're trying to accomplish.  First, I don't think a solution to this problem should involve modifying your `routes` array.  Remove the HeaderFooter component and set up your routing like normal -- don't do anything fancy within the routes to control whether the header or footer is displayed.  All pages, unless you have some other special cases per your app's requirements, should be handled by the same `<router-view />`.  Surrounding it can be your header and footer components that you can then conditionally render based on the current route.  Since you want them displayed on every page except the home page, it should be pretty easy:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <the-header v-if="$route.name !== 'home'" />
    <router-view />
    <the-footer v-if="$route.name !== 'home'" />
  <div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Child route paths are added to parent path.

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/posts',
    component: PostsLayout,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'new',
        component: PostsNew        
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: PostsDetail,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

here child path is like `/posts/new` or `/posts/123`

So without a complete parent definition child routes won't function as expected.

You don't need a rooter definition for header and footer components. You can just load related one in the component.